# adobe illustrator, Different type of text boxes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am really new to adobe illustrator. Was wondering if there are different types of text boxes available in illustrator. i.e something like a bubble text box.
I am using Illustrator CS6

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not natively available in the software. My way of recreating a speech bubble goes by:

1. Create a basic shape
2. Create a curved tail with Pen Tool
3. Use Pathfinder to merge both shapes into one
4. Style it as preferred
5. Add text box inside speech bubble

This tutorial explains it well: [link](http://bobostrom.com/adobe-illustrator-tips/)

There are a bunch of tutorial and vector packs free on the internet. If you want them to always start and be *natively* available in Illustrator, you should use **Symbols** and **Instances**. You can find it under the `Window` menu. *Have in mind that this will only work in your machine.*

If you have Illustrator CC you can use **Libraries** which store your assets in the **cloud** for reusing wherever you have illustrator logged in. Very cool feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Photoshop, you can copy a vector shape from the "Custom Shape Tool" library. There are a couple of text bubbles there.  Read more at: https://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/shapes/custom-shape-tool/